# objective c++ class not working

Tags: objective-c++

I have this in my .hpp file:

```
class MD
{
public:
    static const int Blk = 0;
}
```

And this in a method in .mm file that includes the .hpp file:

```
int i = MD.Blk;
```

the compiler says `error: expected primary-expression before '.' token` on this line.
If I comment it the line out everything works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `::` operator

```
int i = MD::Blk;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to refer static class member variables is using the `::` operator, like this:

```
int i = MD::Blk;
```